# choco and other apps not working when open windows terminal form folder Context Menu

Tags: windows-terminal

If I open the windows terminal by right click inside the folder and choosing "Open in Windows Terminal" some applications like choco, nano and protoc will not work and give me the following error:

```
protoc : The term 'protoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ protoc -h
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (protoc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

this will not happen if I open the terminal from the start menu of Taskbar.

operating system: Windows 11 Pro 21H2 build 22000.527